# synchronous vs async nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have a sample code running in NodeJS

```
 function (){
   ///OPERATION 1

   ///OPERATION 2

}
```

**Considering** none of the operations require any sort of time out, by default would javascript run **both** at the same time or finish operation 1 then operation 2?

Comment: operation 1 then operation 2

Comment: If both operations are asynchronous... They would *start* in order. But, the bulk of their work (the actual I/O, etc.) would be done in parallel and they could complete (their callback is invoked) in either order.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - since node js (and most engines) is single threaded, nothing is ever done in parallel.

Comment: @niry The JavaScript code can't be run in parallel, but the fully-native portion of the work – the portion actually reading the file's contents, querying the database for records, etc., that's written in C/C++ (as [addons](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/addons.html) for Node.js) – can make use of additional threads.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski agree.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Ok, we are playing catch with deleting messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No two lines of JavaScript ever run simultaneously within the same process. Ever.

See [concurrency vs parallelism](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-and-parallelism).

Asynchronous code in Node.js - assuming there are no worker processes involved - is always running with concurrency and never parallelism. Concurrency is easier to program and helps us build complex machinery quickly. To "scale up" you may need to bring in worker processes to do work in parallel.

In your example, if both operations are synchronous, they will run in the order they are written (`1`, `2`). In fact, if operation `1` is synchronous it will always run first no matter what. If both are asynchronous, then how you experience it depends on how long they each take to complete! If operation `1` is asynchronous but operation `2` is synchronous, then they will seem to run in reverse order (`2`, `1`). This has to do with the way functions get scheduled on the [event loop](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-event-loop/), so understanding that will help this all make sense.

---

*Take a breath. Time for a deep dive.*

---

To be clear, in reality, lines of code always get executed in order. We don't have [GOTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto) and the JavaScript engine does not mysteriously jump around to different places. The key thing to understand is that when someone says a function is *asynchronous* it is really also partly *synchronous*. **Something is happening synchronously.** Otherwise it would be an empty function. Instead, it just means that only a tiny bit of work is done synchronously, usually that simply consists of *scheduling work for later*, and then the rest of it happens later.

So above when I said that if they are both asynchronous then "it depends", it's merely the *completion* or *result* of that function (which you experience via a callback or [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)) whose order is undefined in relation to the completion of other asynchronous functions. This isn't the case for fully synchronous functions simply because *the world stops* for synchronous functions.

If you have two functions both trying to retrieve the same data from two different sources, one from your hard disk and one from the internet, which will finish first? If they are both asynchronous, then  it's a trick question. Probably the hard disk is faster, but don't bet your life on it. Still, one of them technically gets kicked off first, synchronously.

This paradigm of scheduling things for later and not waiting for the result before continuing (non-blocking) is one of the ways Node.js manages to have such great performance even without worker processes / parallelism. For I/O in particular, such as reading a file from the disk, there are "quiet periods" of inactivity where there is nothing for the process to do. In this case, waiting before continuing is a huge waste of time. It is more appropriate to use that opportunity to interleave other functions in the meantime. This is what asynchronous functions do. They delay work to allow us to interleave other work. Usually they achieve this via [process.nextTick()](https://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick) or [setImmediate()](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/07/09/the-case-for-setimmediate/).

All that said, nothing in life is free. Delaying work has a cost and if you misuse timers you will slow down your program. The goal is to make everything that has unavoidable delays (like I/O) asynchronous and almost nothing else. However asynchronous behavior "pollutes the stack". Anything that uses an asynchronous function becomes asynchronous in nature. You could return a value synchronously and pretend like it's not the case (make it invisible to the outside world), but that is usually a bad idea because then you cannot propagate errors or the result at all.

If you are still confused about how to look at a program and figure out when everything runs, have a look at [async and await](https://blog.risingstack.com/async-await-node-js-7-nightly/). It is a wonderful way to write asynchronous code that looks like more traditional synchronous code. And it is arriving in Node 7.

Comment: What does it mean for an operation to be 'async'?

Comment: @DilllyBar, that you know when it is started, and have no idea when it will be completed. It could be 1 ms, 1 hour or never. And you don't want your code to wait because, as mentioned, **everything** written in JS *(in that application)* will be frozen untill you got a result. Therefore you use a callback to be notified when you have a response/result, and to process that result *(as soon as it is available)*.

Comment: @Thomas, thanks a lot! Then what about sync operations? When do they end? What is the difference?

Comment: @DilllyBar, They also start immediately and they run as long as it takes to complete. And during that time JS can not do anything else (single thread). It simply executes the code; line by line, left to the right.

Comment: @Thomas, then how can I tell the difference between these two types when looking at a code? For example a Mongoose query is async, but I didnt know that

Comment: I added more detail. Hope it helps. As for "how can I tell", great question! it's difficult if you aren't looking at a full example or the source code. Today, looking at projects that use databases or the filesystem you may see code that looks like `foo().then(bar)`. The use of `.then()` is a clue that `foo()` may return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), making it async. Soon you will start seeing the [async keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: @DilllyBar, besides the mentioned `async` keyword, you can assume that async code will expect you to provide them some kind of "callback" function. Either as an additional argument to the async function or by registering an eventListener before starting the process *(like the complete event on XMLHttpRequest, before you call `send()`)*, maybe as a property on the config-object, and even the function you pass to as promises `then()` can be seen as a callback-function. So if a function doesn't return a result, but instead expects you to register a callback-function in any way, I'd call it async.

Comment: Indeed. Callbacks can fool you, though. For example, [Array#forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not return anything and does require a callback, but nothing about it is async. The [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) has many similar examples. So you should be cautious about assuming a callback means async behavior. Take the time to read the docs, which will often specify if an API is async.